# SQL drop table errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, drop-table, dbo

I'm trying to create a database for a soccer registration application. I'm trying to keep it simple right now and once I feel comfortable then make it more detailed. I'm trying to run my sql but I keep getting these errors. I was wondering if someone could look at my sql because I don't believe there is a foreign key issue (but obviously there is)

Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Could not drop object 'TShirtSizes' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Could not drop object 'TGenders' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 39
There is already an object named 'TGenders' in the database.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TFields') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TFields
IF OBJECT_ID('TAgeGroups') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TAgeGroups
IF OBJECT_ID('TReferees') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TReferees
IF OBJECT_ID('TTeamCoaches') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeamCoaches
IF OBJECT_ID('TCoaches') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TCoaches
IF OBJECT_ID('TStates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TStates
IF OBJECT_ID('TSockSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TSockSizes
IF OBJECT_ID('TPantSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TPantSizes
IF OBJECT_ID('TShirtSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TShirtSizes
IF OBJECT_ID('TTeamPlayers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeamPlayers
IF OBJECT_ID('TPlayers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TPlayers
IF OBJECT_ID('TGenders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TGenders
IF OBJECT_ID('TTeams') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeams
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- create tables
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

create table TTeams
(
    intTeamID       INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strTeam        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TTeams_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTeamID )
)

CREATE TABLE TGenders
(
    intGenderID     INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strGender      VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TGenders_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intGenderID )
)


CREATE TABLE TPlayers
(
    intPlayerID     INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFirstName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strLastName    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strEmail       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,intShirtSizeID INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intPantSizeID  INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intSockSizeID  INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strCity        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,intStateID     INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intGenderID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intAgeGroupID  INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TPlayers_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intPlayerID )
)

CREATE TABLE TTeamPlayers
(
    intTeamPlayerID INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intTeamID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intPlayerID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TTeamPlayers_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTeamPlayerID )
)

CREATE TABLE TShirtSizes
(
    intShirtSizeID  INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strShirtSize   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TShirtSizes_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intShirtSizeID )
)

CREATE TABLE TPantSizes
(
    intPantSizeID   INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strPantSize    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TPantSizes_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intPantSizeID )
)

CREATE TABLE TSockSizes
(
    intSockSizeID   INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strSockSize    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TSockSizes_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intSockSizeID )
)

CREATE TABLE TStates 
(
    intStateID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strState       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TStates_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intStateID )
)

CREATE TABLE TCoaches
(
    intCoachID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFirstName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strLastName    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strCity        Varchar(50)     not null
    ,intStateID     integer         not null
    ,strPhoneNumber varchar(50)     not null
    ,CONSTRAINT TCoaches_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intCoachID )
)

CREATE TABLE TTeamCoaches
(
    intTeamCoachID  INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intTeamID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intCoachID     INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TTeamCoaches_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTeamCoachID )
)

CREATE TABLE TReferees
(
    intRefereeID    INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFirstName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strLastName    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TReferees_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intRefereeID )
)

CREATE TABLE TAgeGroups
(
    intAgeGroupID   INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strAge         VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TAgeGroups_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intAgeGroupID )
)

CREATE TABLE TFields
(
    intFieldID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strFieldName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,intTeamID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intRefereeID   INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TFields_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intFieldID )
)

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #1 & @: Identify and Create Foreign Keys
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- #    Child                               Parent                      Column(s)
-- -    -----                               ------                      ---------
-- 1    TTeamPlayers                        TPlayers                    intPlayerID
-- 2    TPlayers                            TShirtSizes                 intShirtSizeID
-- 3    TPlayers                            TPantSizes                  intPantSizeID
-- 4    TPlayers                            TSockSizes                  intSockSizeID
-- 5    TPlayers                            TStates                     intStateID
-- 6    TPlayers                            TGenders                    intGenderID
-- 7    TPlayers                            TAgeGroups                  intAgeGroupID
-- 8    TTeamCoaches                        TCoaches                    intCoachID
-- 9    TFields                             TTeams                      intTeamID
-- 10   TFields                             TReferees                   intRefereeID


-- 1
ALTER TABLE TTeamPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TTeamPlayers_TPlayers_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intPlayerID ) REFERENCES TPlayers ( intPlayerID )

-- 2
ALTER TABLE TPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TPlayers_TShirtSizes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intShirtSizeID ) REFERENCES TShirtSizes ( intShirtSizeID )

-- 3
ALTER TABLE TPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TPlayers_TPantSizes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intPantSizeID ) REFERENCES TPantSizes ( intPantSizeID )

-- 4
ALTER TABLE TPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TPlayers_TSockSizes_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intSockSizeID ) REFERENCES TSockSizes ( intSockSizeID )

-- 5
ALTER TABLE TPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TPlayers_TStates_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intStateID ) REFERENCES TStates ( intStateID )

-- 6
ALTER TABLE TPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TPlayers_TGenders_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intGenderID ) REFERENCES TGenders ( intGenderID )

-- 7
ALTER TABLE TPlayers ADD CONSTRAINT TPlayers_TAgeGroups_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intAgeGroupID ) REFERENCES TAgeGroups ( intAgeGroupID )

-- 8
ALTER TABLE TTeamCoaches ADD CONSTRAINT TTeamCoaches_TCoaches_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intCoachID ) REFERENCES TCoaches ( intCoachID )

-- 9
ALTER TABLE TFields ADD CONSTRAINT TFields_TTeams_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intTeamID ) REFERENCES TTeams ( intTeamID )

-- 10
ALTER TABLE TFields ADD CONSTRAINT TFields_TReferees_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intRefereeID ) REFERENCES TReferees ( intRefereeID )
```

Comment: Try to drop all related constraints that you can find in the dictionary.

Comment: Can't drop most of your tables before you drop TPlayers since it's full of FK References to those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop in below sequence . First You should drop the tables which has FK so that FK constraint will be droped as well then you can drop child tables.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TTeamPlayers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeamPlayers
IF OBJECT_ID('TPlayers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TPlayers
IF OBJECT_ID('TTeamCoaches') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeamCoaches
IF OBJECT_ID('TFields') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TFields
IF OBJECT_ID('TAgeGroups') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TAgeGroups
IF OBJECT_ID('TReferees') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TReferees
IF OBJECT_ID('TCoaches') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TCoaches
IF OBJECT_ID('TStates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TStates
IF OBJECT_ID('TSockSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TSockSizes
IF OBJECT_ID('TPantSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TPantSizes
IF OBJECT_ID('TShirtSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TShirtSizes
IF OBJECT_ID('TGenders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TGenders
IF OBJECT_ID('TTeams') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeams
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling foreign key constraints first then drop the tables.Finally, enable constraints and triggers again.

```
 EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
    GO
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('TFields') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TFields
    IF OBJECT_ID('TAgeGroups') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TAgeGroups
    IF OBJECT_ID('TReferees') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TReferees
    IF OBJECT_ID('TTeamCoaches') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeamCoaches
    IF OBJECT_ID('TCoaches') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TCoaches
    IF OBJECT_ID('TStates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TStates
    IF OBJECT_ID('TSockSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TSockSizes
    IF OBJECT_ID('TPantSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TPantSizes
    IF OBJECT_ID('TShirtSizes') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TShirtSizes
    IF OBJECT_ID('TTeamPlayers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeamPlayers
    IF OBJECT_ID('TPlayers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TPlayers
    IF OBJECT_ID('TGenders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TGenders
    IF OBJECT_ID('TTeams') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TTeams
    GO
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
    GO
    EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ENABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ?'
    GO
```